# how to print multiple barcode images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode, barcode-printing

I have generated multiple barcodes using this code:

```
function getCode() {
    var multipleCodes = document.getElementById('codeArea').value;
    var eachLine = multipleCodes.split('\n');
    console.log("eachLine = " + eachLine);
    for (var i = 0; i < eachLine.length; i++) {
        console.log("Inside loop: " + eachLine[i]);

        var div = document.createElement('iframe');
        div.innerHTML = "";

        div.setAttribute('id', 'iFrameID' + i);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        document.getElementById('iFrameID' + i).src = 'barCodeGenerator/generateBarCode.php?q=' + eachLine[i];

    }
```

and trying to print it by using this method:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
    var strName = document.getElementById("codeArea").value;
    var imageId = document.getElementsByClassName('decoded');

    var imagObject = new Image();
    imagObject = imageId;
    var originalImage = '<img id="imageViewer" src="' + imageSrc + '" style="padding-top: 20px"   alt="' + imageSrc + '" />';
    popup = window.open('', 'popup', 'toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=700,height=650');
    popup.document.open();
    popup.document.write("<html><head></head><body onload='print()'>");
    popup.document.write(originalImage);
    popup.document.write("</body></html>");
    window.close('popup');
    popup.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () { popup.close(); }, 8000);
}
```

which only print single image by merging all barcodes.
How can i print them separately as multiple images.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you've written this code in Vanilla JavaScript, you may change the "JQuery" to "JavaScript" without loosing any info.

Answer (score 0):

The most part of this code is irrelevant to your question. Consider removing your logs, the parts about showing popup and hiding it for more clearance.

Seems `imageSrc` variable in your code contains the source of one image, so you need to change your code by sending the array of image sources and iterating over it:

```
var originalImage = '';
// assuming imageSrc is an array of image sources
for (var i=; i < imageSrc.length; i++) {

    // note that I'm changing the id of the image a litle bit to ensure it will remain unique
    originalImage  += '<img id="imageViewer' + i + '" src="' + imageSrc[i] + '" style="padding-top: 20px"   alt="' + imageSrc[i] + '" />';

}
```

then the rest of your code must work.

Comment: I did the same but it will not print the barcodes it will only show barCodeGenerator/generateBarCode.php?q='+strName(barcode strings only)

Comment: @NehaDixit if you're using `src="' + imageSrc + '"` to generate the source of image, so it's a url to a physical image file or the base64 equivalent of it. isn't it?

Comment: @NehaDixit nice! now you need to change it to an array of urls of physical images. the just replace my code with line 6 of your code.